# behaviortree-cpp not installing using apt

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, apt

I tried to install behaviortree using `sudo apt install ros-noetic-behaviortree-cpp*` and got the following error while the system installing it:

```
Preparing to unpack .../ros-noetic-behaviortree-cpp-v3_3.8.5-1focal.20230814.151
459_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ros-noetic-behaviortree-cpp-v3 (3.8.5-1focal.20230814.151459) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-noetic-behaviortree-c
pp-v3_3.8.5-1focal.20230814.151459_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/ros/noetic/bin/bt3_log_cat', which is also in package
 ros-noetic-behaviortree-cpp 4.4.2-1focal.20231128.201059
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-noetic-behaviortree-cpp-v3_3.8.5-1focal.20230814.15
1459_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried multiple ways to install it but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acc'd to your output:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-noetic-behaviortree-c
pp-v3_3.8.5-1focal.20230814.151459_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/ros/noetic/bin/bt3_log_cat', which is also in package
 ros-noetic-behaviortree-cpp 4.4.2-1focal.20231128.201059
```

Internally, the `dpkg` command is called on the archived file path `/var/cache/apt/archives/ros-noetic-behaviortree-c pp-v3_3.8.5-1focal.20230814.151459_amd64.deb`. It has an error because it's unable to overwrite `/opt/ros/noetic/bin/bt3_log_cat` as you install the ros-noetic packages.

It seems that you have a conflicting existing package, i.e. ros-noetic-behaviortree-cpp, and that needs to be purged prior to installing the new packages. Based on your command to install all other packages, my best guess is that it's an older package, hence the conflict.

See [man dpkg](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)

Try the following:

```
# Remove the existing package, -P or --purge
sudo dpkg -P ros-noetic-behaviortree-cpp
```

Another way to fix this (not recommend), is to simply force the overwrite when installing with `dpkg`.

```
# Force overwrite
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-noetic-behaviortree-c
pp-v3_3.8.5-1focal.20230814.151459_amd64.deb
```

In either case, follow up with `sudo apt -f install` to fix broken pipes (as your output mentions in the following line for `dpkg-deb`). Then try running your command again.

```
# Fix broken pipes
sudo apt -f install

# Your command
sudo apt install ros-noetic-behaviortree-cpp*
```

Hope this helps.